# softartisans excelwriter - How do I get a date style of dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss?

Tags: .net, officewriter

I can either use `NumberFormat.DateFormat.MonthDayYearHourMinute24` or `NumberFormat.TimeFormat.HourMinuteSecond24` but nothing that will give me the date and the time together along with the seconds :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I am the product owner of OfficeWriter]

If you need a custom date format that is not included in the list of built-in [NumberFormat.DateFormat](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/NumberFormat.DateFormat) enumerations, you can set [Style.NumberFormat](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Style.NumberFormat) to any formatting string you want. In this case, the formatting string needs to be modified to include the second variables:

```
//Get NumberFormat
string numFormat = style.NumberFormat;

//Set NumberFormat
style.NumberFormat = "m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM";
```

The formatting strings accepted by OfficeWriter are the same as those in Excel. To find a new formatting string, you can look up the number format in Excel under **Format Cells > Number**. Select 'Custom' to find the exact formatting string for a particular number format. More information is available in the OfficeWriter documentation under [Number Formats](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/Number+Formats).